# Append selected row of csv to another csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, append, concatenation

I am trying to write a program which will be appending selected column of a csv file to another csv file as a row.

I have this code:

```
def append_pandas(s,d):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=';', header=None)
    df_t = df.T
    df_t.columns = df_t.iloc[0]
    df_new = df_t.drop(0)
    pdb = pd.read_csv(d, sep=';')
    newpd = pdb.append(df_new)
    newpd.to_csv(d)
```

Which does the job only with the first file, like this:

[image]

It is exactly what I want. But when the next file is added, this is what happens:

[image]

And the following file:

[image]

I am pretty confused. How to make them being aligned row by row?..
Please, help :(

P.S. My initial csv file is in this format (that's why I need to select a particular column - Cell Count):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at one time, you save `newpd` using the default separator `','` (by not specifying a separator), and the next time when you read it back, you read it with the separator `';'` which is ofcourse not correct because it is supposed to be `','`.

A fix would be to always use `';'` as your separator, so you need to do `to_csv` like this

```
newpd.to_csv(d, sep=';')
```

If you want to use `','` for your combined dataframe, you just need to be careful on when to read on separator `';'` and when `','`.

**Second approach**

If `files` is the list of file paths to all of your csv files that you want to combine, you can actually do this

```
newpd = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sep=';').set_index('ID').T for file in files])

newpd.to_csv('name.csv', sep=',') # or ';'
```

Here you read each file, set `'ID'` as the index, `.T` to make index become header, and finally concatenate all the resulting dataframes into one, and save it!

Comment: Thank you so so much! It helped :))